# Adding an object into a static collection for a static method

Tags: java, dictionary, static

Probably a stupid question, but it has been driving me nuts for some days.
First of all, I'm speaking about code embedded in a larger application so the class and the method signature is imposed.

So my goal is to create a collection of GC information and the code is the following :

```
public final class JVMMemStats_SVC {
    public static final void JVMMemStats(IData pipeline) throws ServiceException {
        List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> gcMBeans = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
        for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gcBean : gcMBeans){ // Loop against GCs
           GC gc = GCs.get(gcBean.getName());
           if( gc != null ){    // This GC already exists

           } else { // New GC
               GCs.put(
                   gcBean.getName(),
                   new GC( gcBean.getCollectionCount(), gcBean.getCollectionTime())
               );
           }
    }

    public class GC {
        public long Cnt, Duration;

        public GC(long cnt, long duration){
            this.set(cnt, duration);
        }

        public void set(long cnt, long duration){
            this.Cnt = cnt;
            this.Duration = duration;
        }
    }

    static Map<String, GC> GCindexes = new HashMap<String, GC>();
}
```

But I got the following error at compilation time :

```
non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context :
   GCPrev.add( new GC( gcBean.getCollectionCount(), gcBean.getCollectionTime()) );
```

Well ... I'm lost. Thanks for any tip.

Laurent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create an instance of `non-static` inner class `GC` inside the `JVMMemStats()` static method.

```
non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context :
    GCPrev.add( new GC( gcBean.getCollectionCount(), gcBean.getCollectionTime()) );
```

The static context being referred above is the `JVMMemStats()` method. Just change the class declaration to

```
public static class GC {
     // needs to be static to be instantiated in a static method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non static variables ,methods can not be accessed from static mathods. So change the static variables in to non static or change the non static method to static and check.